# Populate a combobox using DirectStore

Tags: extjs

I'm having issues while populating a combobox using DirectStore, the combobox is as follow:

```
this.Combo = new Ext.form.ComboBox({
        fieldLabel: "Name",
        editable: false,
        triggerAction: 'all',
        mode: 'remote',
        store: new Ext.data.DirectStore({
            reader: new Ext.data.JsonReader({
                successProperty: 'success',
                idProperty: 'name',
                root: 'data',
                fields: [ 'name' ]
            }),
            autoLoad: true,
            api: { read: SS.MyApi.getNames }
        }),
        valueField: 'name',
        displayField: 'name'
    });
```

The returned json is:

```
[{"type":"rpc","tid":7,"action":"MyApi","method":"getNames","result":{"success":true,"data":{"name":["name1","name2","name3"]}}}]
```

And the c# code that generates the json

```
[DirectMethod]
public JObject getNames()
{
        List<string> names = new List<string>();
  names.Add("name1");
  names.Add("name2");
  names.Add("name3");

  JObject data = new JObject();
  data.Add(new JProperty("name", names));
        return  new JObject(
                            new JProperty("success", true),
                            new JProperty("data", data)
                    );
}
```

The combobox is showing only one entry with "name1,name2,name3". How can i have one entry per name?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your returned json tells the combobox exactly what to do

```
"data":{"name":["name1","name2","name3"]}
```

i only has 1 field (name) in data and this has the value name1, name2, name3
your json has to look more like this:

```
data : [
   {
      name : "name1"
   }, {
      name : "name2"
   }, {
      name : "name3"
   }
]
```

Comment: Great thanks. Instead of List<string> I should return a List<Dictionary<string, object>>. It's working now

Answer (score 0):

Trick: I don't know how to mapping this yet, but you can convert it to specific type (anonymous) like this (using Linq):

```
var list = names.Select(s => new { name = s });
```

you return 
`JObject` > `JProperty` data 
     |----> `JObject` > `JProperty` name 
          |----> `List<string>`

For me one of the `JObject` > `JProperty` is OPTIONAL, lets said is name... then you reader root is ok (data) and the field should is also mapping correctly with the transformation that we did.

In your code, you return 
`JObject` > `JProperty` data 
     |----> `Enumerable<{name}>`

```
"result":{"success":true,"data":[{"name":"name1"},{"name":"name2"},{"name":"name3"}]}
```

NOTE: Obviously if you know how to mapping string directly you don't have to convert it and will be better.